How to stack FILTER functions when filtering arrays
My spreadsheet is located here, everyone should have edit permissions: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1TGwDf5vTsHbDGiNZBTRHDwVpHZd9lzx2r1abV0ygPBE/edit?usp=sharing
I'm trying to figure out how to stack multiple FILTER() functions in the tab "Oct 19 - Morning" when the range being filtered by each function is an array. I'm trying the following function in the code block, but it's returning an error that says "In ARRAY_LITERAL, an Array Literal was missing values for one or more rows."

={ FILTER( {'Master Sheet'!$C$2:$D,'Master Sheet'!$E$2:$E},SEARCH("",'Master Sheet'!$E$2:$E)) ; FILTER( {'Manual
Addition'!$A$2:$A,'Manual Addition'!$C$2:$C}, SEARCH("",'Manual
Addition'!$C$2:$C)) }

The filters work fine by themselves, but when stacked together they're producing the error.

Is the intended goal to pull and stack 3 columns from Master Sheet & 2 columns from Manual Addition?!

Your question should stand on its own; please don't expect that users must/will open your spreadsheet in order to understand your question. Would you please edit your question to include information about the layout of your data.

You have a formula which is stacks the results of two FILTER commands.
={
FILTER({'Master Sheet'!$C$2:$D,'Master Sheet'!$E$2:$E},SEARCH("",'Master Sheet'!$E$2:$E))
;
FILTER({'Manual Addition'!$A$2:$A, 'Manual Addition'!$C$2:$C}, SEARCH("",'Manual Addition'!$C$2:$C))
}

Though each filter works as a standalone, when stacked it generates an error message

"In ARRAY_LITERAL, an Array Literal was missing values for one or more
rows."

The reason for this is that the number of columns must be the same for each array. In this case,

FILTER({'Master Sheet'!$C$2:$D, 'Master Sheet'!$E$2:$E},SEARCH("", 'Master Sheet'!$E$2:$E)) generates data in three columns ("Clean Name","Experience","Oct-19 Morning")
BUT
FILTER({'Manual Addition'!$A$2:$A,'Manual Addition'!$C$2:$C}, SEARCH("",'Manual Addition'!$C$2:$C)) generates data in only two columns.

The solution is to modify one or other FILTER. Here is an outcome of three columns
={
"Clean Name","Experience","Oct-19 Morning";
FILTER({'Master Sheet'!$C$2:$D, 'Master Sheet'!$E$2:$E},SEARCH("",'Master Sheet'!$E$2:$E));
FILTER({'Manual Addition'!$A$2:$B,'Manual Addition'!$C$2:$C}, SEARCH("",'Manual Addition'!$C$2:$C))
}


SAMPLE - Filter#1


SAMPLE - Filter#2


SAMPLE - Combined Filter with header

